# Which C++ draft?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards

I am interested in having a current C++ standard and I am a little bit confused with links at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/. What is supposed to be the new version? What title should I look for? Is it "*Working Draft, Standard for Programming Language C++*" or "*Programming Languages — C++*"? What's the difference between these papers? Why [N4141](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/prot/14882fdis/n4140.pdf) paper is password-protected while newer [N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) is not?

In question [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents) there's a good list of drafts, but I still can't tell what is the "stable" version of draft, i.e. what can I use as a reference for C++11?

Comment: use N3337 for C++11, and N3936 or N4140 for C++14

Comment: Or if you want the real standard, you can opt for for buying it from you national standard organisation (ex: http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS%2fISO%2fIEC+14882-2012 for US).  But it's only a couple of words away from the drafts you get for free.

Comment: *"what is the "stable" version of draft, i.e. what can I use as a reference for C++11?"* Well, what's your intent? If you want it to check if your compiler is compliant, the International Standard might not help you. For example, clang++ and g++ implement various resolutions to defects in the C++11 Standard in their respective C++11 modes. And if you want to build your own compiler, there's essentially the same question: Do you want to build it against a defective, but stable International Standard, or which fixes do you incorporate?

Comment: Draft C++ standards are free; the official standards are not. N4141 is password-protected because it is the official standard document for C++14; N4296 is free because it is a draft document for the next version, C++17.

Comment: *What do the descriptions of C++ Standards drafts mean?* is NOT a request for an off-site resource.  C'mon people, did you read the question?